# Store sentence with punctuation in C++

Tags: c++, punctuation, sentence

It's my first time here and I am a beginner at C++. I would like to know how I can split sentences with punctuation mark while I am reading from a text file.

i.e.

```
hey how are you? The Java is great. Awesome C++ is awesome!
```

The result would be this in my vector (assuming I have put endl to display each content of the vector):

- hey how are you?
- The Java is great.
- Awesome C++ is awesome!

Here's my code so far:

```
vector<string> sentenceStorer(string documentOfSentences)
{
ifstream ifs(documentOfSentences.c_str());
string word;
vector<string> sentence;
while ( ifs >> word )
{

    char point = word[word.length()-1];
    if (point == '.' || point == '?' || point == '!')
    {

        sentence.push_back(word);
    }
}
 return sentence;

}

void displayVector (vector<string>& displayV)
{
    for(vector<string>::const_iterator i = displayV.begin(); i != displayV.end(); ++i )
    {
        cout << *i <<endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector <string> readstop = sentenceStorer("input.txt");
    displayVector(readstop);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my result:

- you?
- great.
- awesome!

Can you explain why I couldn't get the previous word and fix that?

Comment: What about elipsis...?

Comment: What about a makeshift interrobang?!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is usually best if you share some code of what you already have, ideally as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). For example, even in your case, you could post the boilerplate of the loop which reads the text file, and even your attempts of what you have tried to achieve what you want.

Comment: What about abbrev., did you take those into account? There are also other examples where a `.` doesn't end a sentence, e.g. e.g.

Comment: Why do you have so many parentheses in your `while` condition?  You could use just `while (getline(ifs, word, '.') || getline(ifs, word, '?') || getline(ifs, word, '!'))` with 8 parentheses, instead of the 18 in your code fragment.  And the fewer parentheses will actually make your code easier to read — use them to make the intent clear, not because they're pretty.  If you really like them that much, take up LISP (Lot's of Irritating Silly Parentheses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a clue. In while statement you have three conditions in the or clause. So if any of them is fulfilled than the `while` statement do not check other ones. So it takes your first and looks for . (dot). Then after finding it, reads it into the `word`, so in fact it omits question mark. 
It looks you need to find other way to solve this. If I were you, I would read whole line and parse it char by char. As far as I am concerned there is no build-in string function that splits words by delimiter.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it.